# Many different links to copy

Tags: jquery, clipboard, copying

```
var ShortCut = document.querySelector('.Copy_Link');
ShortCut.addEventListener('click', function(event)
{
    var ShortCut = document.querySelector('.Copy_Container');
    ShortCut.focus();
    ShortCut.select();
try
{
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful? 'successful': 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying the shortcut is ' + msg);
}
catch (err)
{
    console.log('Unsuccessful copying.');
}
});
```

This is a script for copying one link from the hidden text area. I want to have several separate links on the same page, but this script:

```
var ShortCut = document.querySelectorAll('.Copy_Link1, .Copy_Link2, .Copy_Link3');
ShortCut.addEventListener('click', function(event)
{
    var ShortCut = document.querySelectorAll('.Copy_Container1, .Copy_Container2, .Copy_Container3');
    ShortCut.focus();
    ShortCut.select();
try
{
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful? 'successful': 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying the shortcut is ' + msg);
}
catch (err)
{
    console.log('Unsuccessful copying.');
}
});
```

Failed.

Links:

```
<SPAN class="Copy_Link1">Copy the shortcut link 1</SPAN>
<TEXTAREA class="Copy_Container1" Hidden ReadOnly>
TEXT FOR COPYING INTO CLIPBOARD 1
</TEXTAREA>

<SPAN class="Copy_Link2">Copy the shortcut link 2</SPAN>
<TEXTAREA class="Copy_Container2" Hidden ReadOnly>
TEXT FOR COPYING INTO CLIPBOARD 2
</TEXTAREA>

<SPAN class="Copy_Link3">Copy the shortcut link 3</SPAN>
<TEXTAREA class="Copy_Container3" Hidden ReadOnly>
TEXT FOR COPYING INTO CLIPBOARD 3
</TEXTAREA>
```

I hope you understand what I want. I could not find even a similar solution that works in my particular case, I tried several methods, but only this one works. If something is unclear, feel free to ask.

Comment: You could put a `data-target` on the span to identify which textarea to copy, and reference that in your event handler

Comment: How to reference it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a data element on the span to tell it which textarea to select.

```js
$('.Copy_Link').on('click', function(e){
  var target = document.getElementById(this.dataset.target);
  
  target.focus();
  target.select();
  
  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying the shortcut is ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Unsuccessful copying.');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<SPAN class="Copy_Link" data-target="Copy_Container1">Copy the shortcut link 1</SPAN>
<TEXTAREA id="Copy_Container1" Hidden ReadOnly>
TEXT FOR COPYING INTO CLIPBOARD 1
</TEXTAREA>

<SPAN class="Copy_Link" data-target="Copy_Container2">Copy the shortcut link 2</SPAN>
<TEXTAREA id="Copy_Container2" Hidden ReadOnly>
TEXT FOR COPYING INTO CLIPBOARD 2
</TEXTAREA>

<SPAN class="Copy_Link" data-target="Copy_Container3">Copy the shortcut link 3</SPAN>
<TEXTAREA id="Copy_Container3" Hidden ReadOnly>
TEXT FOR COPYING INTO CLIPBOARD 3
</TEXTAREA>
```